# BackboneJS + Requirejs: Backbone is null issue

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

In the router.js. The firebug console alerts Backbone is null there. Why???

**app.js**

```
define([
  'order!jQuery',
  'order!Underscore',
  'order!Backbone',
  'order!router'  // Request router.js
],
function($, _, Backbone, Router){

    App = {
        initialize: function() {

            console.log("app.js initalize");
            Router.initialize();
        }
    };

    return App;
});
```

**router.js**

```
define([
   'order!Underscore',
   'order!Backbone'
],
function(_, Backbone){

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({      
        // Console shows Backbone is null here, why? 
        // I'm sure the config is correct.
        routes: {

            '*actions': "defaultAction"
        },

        defaultAction: function(actions){
            // We have no matching route, lets just log what the URL was
            console.log('No route:', actions);
        }
    });

    var initialize = function(){
        console.log("Router initialize");
        var app_router = new AppRouter;

        Backbone.history.start();
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone does not support the AMD and it doesn't register as module. When required it registers normally as a global Backbone object, also since 1.3 Underscore doesn't support AMD neither and if you will require Backbone and Underscore under Backbone and _ namespaces they will overwrite its values in this modules scope to `undefined` cause of that.

jQuery supports AMD but it also registers itself as a global instance. Basically it means that you don't need to require jquery, underscore and backbone multiple times - it's enough if you do it once in your requirejs main script

Comment: Since it doesn't support AMD, is it still good to use requires? Would there be more issues coming after when performing production build? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It works perfectly fine with AMD it just doesn't register as AMD module but rather then that it registers in the global scope. We've used requirejs and backbone when building http://wunderkit.com and can't imagine not using these two! :)

Comment: You can also grab an AMD compliant version of Backbone and Underscore here...https://github.com/amdjs

Comment: i'm lost. What should i do to correct the issue? I have the same issue. Also this one. "Module name 'underscore' has not been loaded yet for context: _" but when i refresh it disappears. its weird.

Comment: just don't add it as a defined modules dependencies - require them once and the access them from global scope rather then requiring to each amd module

Answer (score -2):

The alternative is to hack the backbone.js library.

Note: This will allow you to reference Backbone.js and underscore.js library within your require.js defines, but it will not stop them from being added to the global namespace/window object. This requires a little more hacking.

1. Find:

   ```
   (function(){var l=this,y=
   ```
2. Replace it with:

   ```
   define('backbone',['underscore','jquery'],function(_,$){
   var l = this;
   (function(){var y=
   ```
3. Add this to the bottom of the page:

   ```
   return l.Backbone;
   });
   ```

Then do the same for underscore.js

1. Prefix the beginning with:

   ```
   define('underscore',function(){
   ```
2. Add to the bottom of the page:

   ```
   return this._;
   });
   ```